# Trying to calculate a percentage of possible answers that have been selected in a pdf

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, adobe-indesign

I have multiple forms that all follow a similar format, and that are exported from an InDesign table into Acrobat DC and then prepared as fillable forms. These track a student’s progress with a series of tasks (lines of text from the original InDesign file) and a rating of either 1, 2, or 3 (prepared as radio buttons with 3 choices) for each task.
I need to create a field to calculate the percentage of radio buttons that have been chosen (i.e., if there are 10 lines [hence 10 radio-button sets] and 4 have an entry choice selected, the field I want to create would return “40”--4 out of 10 radio-button-sets have a selection made=40%).  I would LIKE to be able to calculate this percentage based on only those button choices that are a “2” or a “3” (passing grades), but I could eliminate the “1” choice and turn that into a check box, meaning that the script would only need to act on “any choice selected” instead of 2 out of the 3 choices.

---

[image: screenshot example of form lines]

---

Acrobat DC allows for a text box to be designated as a calculated field using JavaScript, but I have never even tried to use JS before.
Can anyone help me with a script that will divide the number of radio buttons that have a choice selected (n) by the total number of radio buttons (t), and then return that percentage (%) [n/t=%]? Since the line on which this field will be placed already has a percentage sign already in place (in the original InDesign text), it would be ideal for this percentage to be returned as a whole number (in the above example, “40” not “40%” or “.4” but I can remove that sign if I must.

Comment: Yes, there are people willing to help you here, but you have to make some effort on your own as well.

Comment: Okay, I get that. Sorry, I guess I'm in the wrong place. Here's my dilemma: my boss threw this request at me halfway through this project. I don't know how to code, and so would be willing to pay someone a reasonable amount to write this for me. Can anyone suggest the appropriate venue/website to seek out that kind of help? And thanks so much for not just kicking me off the forum.

Comment: I've used freelancer.com and upwork.com before, they have a lot of developers available for hire. Don't go too strongly by my words though, there could be better sources I'm unaware of.

Comment: Thanks again, Ray. I was successful at hiring a developer on Guru.com who was quick and reasonably priced. Caveat emptor, they charge a 2.5% surcharge on the fees you pay, AND they collect from the developer, too! It seems that most freelance sites do this, and maybe I'm wrong, but that practice seems wrong to me! Anyway, I really appreciate stackoverflow.com, and you.